# Is there a way of avoiding this error message? "Couldn't resolve resource @string/todo Tip: Try to refresh the layout."

Tags: android-studio

I'm creating drafts of an app and I keep receiving the aforementioned error on numerous iterations. I feel like I might have mistakenly revalued the relevant string within the JRE / JDK somehow but I'm not 100% sure

I'm new to the game but have followed all recommended actions within Android Studio help prompts. And it keeps creating new strings within res->values->strings

not sure which section of code to include here

I expect this not to be an issue but it keeps reoccuring.

Comment: <ImageView........android:contentDescription="@string/todo"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try adding a string resource in `strings.xml` at

```
<string name="todo">TODO</string>
```

The file is located at `res/values/strings.xml`.
Then rebuild the Android project through Ctrl+F9 key combination.

Comment: `but have followed all recommended actions within Android Studio help prompts. And it keeps creating new strings within res->values->strings` - OP already has

Comment: share the error in detail and your strings.xml file content as well.